# NHibernate - Select full records from aggregates

Tags: .net, nhibernate, aggregate-functions

In short: Given an aggregate query (one with Max, Min, Count, etc) in NHibernate, how can you modify the query to also return the *full record* associated with the aggregated value?

My example: I have 2 tables: `People` (primary key: PersonId) with a 1-to-many relationship to `Events` (primary key: EventId; other columns: PersonId, EventDate).

I want to select the *last event per person* and generate *a list of these events*.  The SQL for *last event per person* would be something like `SELECT PersonId, Max(EventDate) FROM ... GROUP BY PersonId`.  So far the NHibernate query looks like:

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Event>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("PersonId"))
        .Add(Projections.Max("EventDate"))
    );
```

Now what I really need is the *full event info*.  One solution, in theory, is to essentially join the above criteria to the `Events` table by PersonId and the max EventDate (easy enough in plain SQL).  However I'm at a loss of how to perform this in NHibernate.

I'm open to any suggestion (HQL, LINQ, etc.) so long as it avoids stored procedures and views and is limited to 1 or just a few queries.  Issuing a query per Person will not be scalable or performant in my case.

Comment: with NH, I don't think you can join on a derived aggregate table (which would be the optimal query). However you can add a top 1 correlated subquery to the where clause to get the same resultset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you are also open to QueryOver (this can be converted to ICriteria)...

```
Event eventAlias = null;

var topEventsByPerson = Session.QueryOver<Event>(() => eventAlias)
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.EventId).Eq(QueryOver.Of<Event>()
        .Where(x => x.Person == eventAlias.Person)
        .OrderBy(x => x.EventDate).Desc
        .Select(x => x.EventId)
        .Take(1))
    .List();
```

Comment: Joe, this looks like a simple and elegant solution. However I'm getting an ArgumentNullException when referring to eventAlias in `Session.QueryOver<Event>(() => eventAlias)`. Some googling shows that this may be an issue with NHibernate 3.1 but I'm unable to upgrade to 3.2 (I use FluentHibernate which still targets 3.1). Any thoughts?

Comment: oh, I think the issue with using the root alias in other expressions is that you can only go 1 level deep into it's properties. If you want to go more than 1 level deep, you'll need to `JoinAlias` for that field and use that alias. That's exactly why I did `x.Person == eventAlias.Person` instead of using `x.Person.id == eventAlias.Person.id`

Comment: I'm only going 1 level deep too and I'm getting that exception.

Comment: I didn't follow this solution because of the aforementioned exception, but some quick research shows that this should work. The solution I ended up using is posted as a separate answer but I prefer dotjoe's solution because of it's brevity and because it is pure NHibernate code with no SQL.

Comment: weird, I tested the same query (different objects) against NH 3.1.0.4000 and it works on my machine...

Answer (score 1):

Although I prefer dotjoe's answer I wasn't able to implement it because of an ArgumentNullException thrown when using a QueryOver alias.  I suspect this is a bug in NHibernate 3.1.

Instead I found a solution using **ISession.CreateSQLQuery()** where I write the query in plain SQL:

```
var results = session.CreateSQLQuery(@"
        SELECT Events.*
        FROM Events
        join (
                SELECT MAX(EventDate) as MaxEventDate, PersonId
                FROM Events
                GROUP BY PersonId
            )
            as q_LastEventsPerPerson
            on  (Events.EventDate = q_LastEventsPerPerson.MaxEventDate)
            and (Events.PersonId = q_LastEventsPerPerson.PersonId)
    ")
    .AddEntity(typeof(Event))
    .List<Event>();
```

The **AddEntity()** method is key here.  It causes the automatic mapping of the results to objects of type **Event**.

I do not recommend this approach unless you have no alternative.