# Nhibernate 3.0 IQueryOver group by and fetch one entire record in each group which satisfy the condition

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, queryover

My requirement is to fetch the SiteItemOnHand records, group by Businessunitid,inventoryitemid and get the whole SiteItemOnHand record in each group which is having max(lastmodifiedtimestamp)

I am trying to write nhibernate equivalent query for the below sql query

```
Select x.* from 
(
Select  businessunitid,inventoryitemid,max(lastmodifiedtimestamp) as maxvalue from InventoryItemBUOnHand  
group by businessunitid,inventoryitemid HAVING inventoryitemid in (939) and businessunitid=829
) as x
inner join
(
    Select  businessunitid,inventoryitemid,lastmodifiedtimestamp,inventoryitemonhandid from InventoryItemBUOnHand 
    where inventoryitemid in (939) and businessunitid=829
) as y
on x.businessunitid=y.businessunitid and  x.inventoryitemid =y.inventoryitemid and x.maxvalue=y.lastmodifiedtimestamp
```

I have so many limitations. I am only allowed to use Nhibernate 3.0 version and also writing sql queries (Criteria) strictly prohibited.
I was able to write only half part of the query which is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var query= _session.QueryOver<SiteItemOnHand>()
      .Where(x => x.Businessunitid == siteID)
      .Where(x => x.End == endDate)
      .Where(x => x.CountID != filterCount.ID)
      .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.ItemID).IsIn(itemIdList.ToArray())
      .SelectList(list => list
      .SelectMax(x => x.LastModifiedTimestamp)
      .SelectGroup(x => x.Businessunitid)
      .SelectGroup(x => x.ItemId));
```

The above query is generating the below SQL Query which only returns the three columns, but i need entire record because after retriving the record i need to update. I need to fetch all the SiteItemOnHand records which satisfies the above query.

```
SELECT max(this_.lastmodifiedtimestamp) as y0_, this_.businessunitid as y1_, this_.inventoryitemid as y2_ 
FROM InventoryItemBUOnHand this_ 
WHERE this_.businessunitid = 567 and this_.enddate = '1/31/2019 1:18:17 AM' and not (this_.itemcountid = 958) 
and this_.inventoryitemid in (744,755)
GROUP BY this_.businessunitid, this_.inventoryitemid
```

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have data like this and you want the marked records. I don't know if `iventoryitemonhandid` is the `id` of the table, so I'm not relying on that.

```
Table InventoryItemBUOnHand (mapped as SiteItemOnHand)

| businessunitid|inventoryitemid|lastmodifiedtimestamp|inventoryitemonhandid|
|            829|            939|  2019-01-01 00:00:00|                  100| <--
|            829|            940|  2019-01-02 00:00:00|                  101| 
|            829|            940|  2019-01-03 00:00:00|                  102| <-- 
|            829|            950|  2019-01-04 00:00:00|                  103| 
|            829|            950|  2019-01-10 00:00:00|                  104| <--
|            829|            950|  2019-01-06 00:00:00|                  105|
```

If yes, then I'd use a SubQuery like in this question:
[SO: NHibernate - Select full records from aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8154930/634872)

Modified (not tested) to your requirements it would look something like this:

```
int siteID = 829;
List<int> itemIdList = new List<int>() { 939, 940, 950 };
SiteItemOnHand siAlias = null;

var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<SiteItemOnHand>()
    .Where(x => x.Businessunitid == siAlias.Businessunitid)
    .And(x => x.ItemID == siAlias.ItemID)
    .Select(Projections.Max<SiteItemOnHand>(y => y.lastmodifiedtimestamp));

var siteItems = Session.QueryOver<SiteItemOnHand>(() => siAlias)
    .Where(x => x.Businessunitid == siteID)
    .AndRestrictionOn(x => x.ItemID).IsIn(itemIdList.ToArray())
    .WithSubquery.Where(x => siAlias.lastmodifiedtimestamp == subQuery.As<DateTime>())
    .List();
```

The goal here is to use a Subquery to filter the correct max dates per group and then use that to filter the actual records.

The resulting SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT <field_list> FROM InventoryItemBUOnHand 
WHERE Businessunitid = 829
AND inventoryitemid in (939, 940, 950)
AND this_.lastmodifiedtimestamp = 
   (SELECT max(this_0_.lastmodifiedtimestamp) as y0_ 
       FROM InventoryItemBUOnHand this_0_ 
       WHERE this_0_.Businessunitid = this_.Businessunitid and this_0_.ItemID = this_.ItemID)
```

**Caution:** Comparing `lastmodifiedtimestamp` may cause unwanted results when two records have the same value for the same `businessunitid` and `inventoryitemid`. If that can happen, you can add an `OrderBy` and select the first record only. It becomes even simpler if `inventoryitemonhandid` is a unique index.

Comment: I forgot to mention . We have a composite key  (businessunitid,inventoryitemid,InventoryItemBUOnHandID)